# ANDROID fragment inside a custom dialog in activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, fragment

I would like to put a fragment inside a custom dialog in activity.

**I receive this error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c007e (copyworld.rebootcw:id/container_schedule1) for fragment FragmentGiorno{418215c0 #0 id=0x7f0c007e}
```

**This is my code:**

layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_dialog_schedulazione"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/container_schedule1">

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Popup_schedule();
}


//******POPUP PER LA SCHEDULAZIONE******************

public void Popup_schedule() {
    dialog_schedule=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog_schedule.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog_schedule.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_schedule);
    dialog_schedule.setCancelable(false);
    lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    window = dialog_schedule.getWindow();
    lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog_schedule.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    window = dialog_schedule.getWindow();
    window.setAttributes(lp);


                 FragmentGiorno fragment = new FragmentGiorno();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_schedule1, fragment);
                 fragmentTransaction.commit();

    dialog_schedule.show();

}
}
```

How I add a fragment inside a custom dialog in **MainActivity.java** that extend Activity?

Comment: I haven't tested this but wanted to point out a couple of potential points - `onCreate()` is setting the content view to `R.id.activity_main` but your post mentions `layout.xml`. Just checking that this is actually `activity_main.xml` inside your res / layout folder. Secondly, `android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_dialog_schedulazione"` shouldn't contain a + after the @ sign as the element you are referring to should have it's own ID (instead of trying to create one)

Comment: Is your `activity_main.xml` contains the `FrameLayout` with id `container_schedule1` ??

Comment: sorry, my layout is activity_main.xml

Comment: container_schedule1 is situated in dialog_custom.xml

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 dialog_schedule.findViewById(R.id.container_schedule1)
```

**Instead Of**

```
 R.id.container_schedule1
```

In your Code

Comment: i try this: FrameLayout container_schedule=(FrameLayout)dialog_schedule.findViewById(R.id.container_schedule);

Comment: put the container_schedule to fragment replace or direct as my answer

Answer (score -1):

> If you want to load fragment inside dialog then you can use `DialogFragment` instead.

Below is the working example of using `DialogFragment`.

```
public class Demo extends DialogFragment{

View mainView;

LinearLayout layoutArrow;

Bundle bundle;
ArrayList<BookingDetail> bookingDetails;
View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
public static Demo newInstance(@NonNull ArrayList<BookingDetail> bookingDetails) {
    Demo alertPopUpMapReservedBedInfo = new Demo();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("bookingDetails", bookingDetails);
    alertPopUpMapReservedBedInfo.setArguments(args);

    return alertPopUpMapReservedBedInfo;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.InvitationDialogWithSimpleAnim);
    bundle = getArguments();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_info, container, false);
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    layoutArrow = (LinearLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.layoutArrow);

 FragmentGiorno fragment = new FragmentGiorno();
             android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                     this.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_schedule1, fragment);
             fragmentTransaction.commit();
}



@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    if(onClickListener!=null){
        onClickListener.onClick(null);
    }
}
}
```

And call it by,

```
    Demo newFragment = Demo.newInstance(bookingDetails);
    newFragment.show(ft,"dialog");
```

Comment: Why do people misunderstand these questions... A dialogfragment and a fragment inside a dialog (per OP's question) are not the same thing. A fragment might already have code and logic inside, a dialogfragment is basically writing another fragment from scratch